# in which table find query_cache plsql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to know that how should i access my current query_cache size in oracle pl/sql?
is there alternative of "show variables like" in plsql

Comment: Were you thinking of something like [v$parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/V-PARAMETER.html)? It's unrelated to PL/SQL though, and I am not sure what you mean by "quer_cache size".

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [RESULT_CACHE_MAX_SIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams206.htm#REFRN10272)?

You can query it from `v$parameter` ...

```
select * from v$parameter
where name = 'result_cache_max_size'
;
```

... but only if your user has the SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE or SELECT ANY DICTIONARY privilege.